# how to return boolean if certain color exist in captured area using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, detection

I am new to python and just started learning it on my own and I cannot find exact solution to my problem.

here's what I'm trying to do.

1. Capture image using
2. find whether certain color (eg. red, blue green) exist in the captured image
3. return boolean

i have spent couple of days searching for the answer but i cannot find any.

the only thing i know is to use openCV...

I guess the solution is too simple to ask. I am fairly new to computer language,
so i would really appreciate as detailed as possible. thanks!

Comment: Plz show us the code(What you have tried so far?) so that we will be able to help you.

Comment: You may use NumPy. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138339/finding-the-x-y-indexes-of-specific-r-g-b-color-values-from-images-stored-in) for example.

Comment: Post an example image.  Use color thresholding with cv2.inRange(). Then count the number of white pixels using np.nonzero() or test the cv2.mean() of the thresholded image. If zero (totally black), then you have no color in the original. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Use color thresholding with cv2.inRange(). Then either count the number of white pixels using np.nonzero() or test the average over the thresholded image with cv2.mean().

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('red_brushed.png')

# set red range
lowcolor = (0,0,255)
highcolor =(128,128,255)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lowcolor, highcolor)

# Method 1: count number of white pixels and test if zero
count = np.sum(np.nonzero(thresh))
print("count =",count)
if count == 0:
    print("Not Red")
else:
    print("Red")

print("")

# Method 2: get the average of the image and test if zero
average = cv2.mean(thresh)[0]
print("average =",average)
if average == 0:
    print("Not Red")
else:
    print("Red")

# write thresholded image to disk
cv2.imwrite("red_brushed_thresh.png", thresh)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Textual Results:

```
count = 3534485
Red

average = 6.933746337890625
Red
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post while looking for a method to check if a certain color appeared in an image. I wanted to test the time it took to process either method.

Continuing with @fmw42's post:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

# read image
img = cv2.imread('red_brushed.png')

# set red range
lowcolor = (0,0,255)
highcolor =(128,128,255)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lowcolor, highcolor)

t0 = time.process_time()

# Method 1: count number of white pixels and test if zero
count = np.sum(np.nonzero(thresh))
print(f"count = {count}")
if count == 0:
    print("Not Red")
else:
    print("Red")

print("")

t1 = time.process_time() - t0
print(f"Sum Method time elapsed {t1}")

t2 = time.process_time()

# Method 2: get the average of the image and test if zero
average = cv2.mean(thresh)[0]
print(f"average ={average}")
if average == 0:
    print("Not Red")
else:
    print("Red")

# write thresholded image to disk
cv2.imwrite("red_brushed_thresh.png", thresh)

t3 = time.process_time() - t2
print(f"Average Method time elapsed {t2}")
```

This produced the general output of:

```
Sum Method time elapsed 0.0013151379999999935
Average Method time elapsed 0.186069437
```

Using `sum()` and `np.nonzero()` always proved to be quicker.