# Find a pixel of Specific Color in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm a newbie of python, cv2, numpy.
I want to get coordinate of a pixel which have red color.

I thought np.where can do this plan, but I failed it.
finally, I made something terrible.
but, it works.

Can you give a better choice?

```
sought = np.array([10, 10, 140])
gray = np.array([50, 50, 255])

# print(np.where((img > sought) & (img < gray), 0, img))

for x in range(img.shape[1]):
    for y in range(img.shape[0]):

        if img[y,x,:][0] > sought[0]:
            if img[y,x,:][1] > sought[1]:
                if img[y,x,:][2] > sought[2]:
                    if img[y,x,:][0] < gray[0]:
                        if img[y,x,:][1] < gray[1]:
                            if img[y,x,:][2] < gray[2]:
                                print(x)
                                print(y)
                                print("############################################")
```

Comment: Does this solve the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138339/finding-the-x-y-indexes-of-specific-r-g-b-color-values-from-images-stored-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better approach:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg')

sought = np.array([10, 10, 140])
gray = np.array([50, 50, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(img, sought, gray)

coordinates = np.argwhere(mask > 0)
for coord in coordinates:
    x, y = coord
    print("X coordinate:", x)
    print("Y coordinate:", y)
    print("##################")
```